# CorePlot-CocoaTouch plot form specific defines error?

Tags: ios, xcode5, core-plot

Hi i am new to `CorePlot` framework. I tried to integrate `CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj` with my `Xcode` project. I followed the below link
https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki/Using-Core-Plot-in-an-Application
instruction of `iOS Application Dependent Project Install` for integrate with my project.

After integration i build `CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj` project, there is no error and build success.

But when i try to compile my project, it show the following screen shot errors:
[image]

But the reason of this error is my `CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj` project referencing `MacOnly` folder from framework, but i don't know why is getting referenced, because this `CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj` project only for iOS.

If there is anything i am missing or any suggestion most welcome. Thank is advance....

I am using `CorePlot_1.5` and `XCode5.1.1`

Comment: is your selected target is correct?

Comment: yes i done in correct way.

Comment: I am asking this because NSImage is in not available in iOS and you have selected iphone to run

Comment: that's only my problem, i am linking the `CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj` from framework of `CorePlot` but it refereeing `MacOnly` file also.

Comment: Have you checked target dependencies for this project?

Comment: Yes i included `CorePlot-CocoaTouch` library also which is mentioned in that instruction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71480/discussion-between-nagarajan-and-nirmal-choudhari).